# The Serverless Function exceeds the maximum size limit of 50mb

Tags: python, django, web-deployment, vercel

I am trying to deploy my Django project on Vercel and when I am deplying my project it is giving the error -

"The Serverless Function "StockChart/wsgi.py" is 128.14mb which exceeds the maximum size limit of 50mb."

I have attached the GitHub repository of my project below -

[GitHub](https://github.com/tusharrusia/StockChart)

I have tried to minimise the modules in requirements.txt and only kept the essential modules but then also it is giving the same error.

Comment: i am getting the same error and think that pandas with numpy is the reason the size is this high. Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: Not yet, I shifted to Railways, there is no limit like vercel there.

Comment: Update: Railways also ended its Free Tier. Using Render ( I experienced the free tier bit slow to load) and pythonanywhere (By Anaconda and Robust)